# Regex - find a date pattern in a string

Tags: python, regex, date

I am struggling with python regex, feeling my problem is easy but I am stuck.
I try to identify a date sub-string with a strict format YYYY-MM-DD, inside a string. Quite simple. But I want to be sure that the regex is not detecting false positive results.
Some examples of source string that I need to proceed:

```
string1='foo2012-09-2018-09-03foo'
string2='2012-09-2018-09-03'
```

I want to extract the string representing the date string `2018-09-03` and **not** this string `2012-09-20`. I have tried various pattern. 
Basic one is something like :

```
import re
string1='foo2012-09-2018-09-03foo'
string2='2012-09-2018-09-03'
pattern  = '[\d]{4}[-_.][\d]{2}[-_.][0-3][\d]'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string1):
    print(match)
    # FAIL : <re.Match object; span=(3, 13), match='2012-09-20'>
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string2):
    print(match)
    # FAIL : <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='2012-09-20'>
```

Ok not working, let's change the pattern to check if previous and next char are not a digit:

```
pattern  = '[\D][\d]{4}[-_.][\d]{2}[-_.][0-3][\d][\D]'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string1):
    i, j = match.span()
    if string1[i] not in '0123456789': i+=1
    if string1[j] not in '0123456789': j-=1
    print(string1[i:j])
    # SUCCESS : 2018-09-03 
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string2):
    i, j = match.span()
    if string2[i] not in '0123456789': i+=1
    if string2[j] not in '0123456789': j-=1
    print(string2[i:j])
    # FAIL : no match !
```

Second one is not working because in `string2` there is no char after the sub-string I am looking for. Is there a way to adjust the pattern to say look for date followed by a non decimal digit or end of the string?

PS: first post!

Comment: What you're looking for is a negative lookahead:  `(?![0-9])` at the end of you pattern.

Comment: `\d` and `\D` are to be used without brackets.

Comment: @joanis: Whaou this is a prompt answer. Thanks I will look at negative lookahead ... clearly I am not familiar with the concept

Comment: @JohnnyWezel Indead. Thx

Comment: @joanis this does the job. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example if it helps...

```
import re

#using a list as output can then be looped for this example
strings = ['foo2012-09-2018-09-03foo', '2012-09-2018-09-03']

#Is there a way to adjust the pattern to say look for date followed by a non decimal digit or end of the string?
#Yes! :o) Use a non-capturing group for 'not a number or the end of the line' which is: (?:\D|$)
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?:\D|$)')

for string in strings:
    print(pattern.search(string)[1])

for string in strings:
    print(pattern.findall(string))
```

Outputs:

```
2018-09-03
2018-09-03
['2018-09-03']
['2018-09-03']
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example. 
The use of negative lookahead assertion (`(?!\d)`) is shorter than lookahead assertion as proposed in your example (`(?:\D|$)`). Both are doing the job, just a question of preference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **joanis**, the answer is negative lookahead:

```
import re
pattern  = '(?<!\d)\d{4}[-_.]\d{2}[-_.][0-3]\d(?!\d)'
string1='foo2012-09-2018-09-03foo'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string1):
    i, j = match.span()
    print(string1[i:j])
    # WORK : 2018-09-03

string2='2012-09-2018-09-03'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, string2):
    i, j = match.span()
    print(string2[i:j])
    # WORK : 2018-09-03
```